# Cost function value with gredient descent optamization increases after n epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, gradient-descent, multilabel-classification

I am working on creating a neural network for multilabel text document classification.
I have a vocabulary of 3750 words stored in a Vector (V).

For each input document, I create a vector (I) of size 3750. If a term from input document is found in vocabulary at x index in vector(V), the x index in the vector is marked as 1 otherwise 0. Example.
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0,1, ...., 0]

For the Labels, I have a vocabulary of 1500 labels stored in a Vector (L).
Like above I created a vector (LB) for each document and marked the ith index as 1 if the document has label x.

The label data is also represented as vector with 1550 elements, like [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...., 0]. i-th element indicates whether the i-th label is a positive label for a text. The number of labels for a text differs depending on texts.

Here is my code.

```
from __future__ import division
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time

def csv_to_numpy_array(filePath, delimiter):
    return np.genfromtxt(filePath, delimiter=delimiter, dtype=None)


def import_data():
    print("Load training data")
    trainX = csv_to_numpy_array("/home/shahzeb/temp/train_data/trainX.csv", delimiter=",")
    trainY = csv_to_numpy_array("/home/shahzeb/temp/train_data/trainY.csv", delimiter=",")
    return trainX, trainY


startTime = time.time()
trainX, trainY = import_data()

learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 500

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 3560 # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 3560 # 2nd layer number of features
n_input = trainX.shape[1]
n_classes = trainY.shape[1]

# tf Graph input
input_neurons = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input],name="input")
known_outputs = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes],name="labels")


def model(x):

    with tf.name_scope("Relu_activation"):
        # Hidden layer with RELU activation
        w1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1]), name="w")
        b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1]), name="b")
        layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w1), b1)
        layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
        # Hidden layer with sigmoid activation
    with tf.name_scope("Sigmoid"):
        w2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2]), name="w")
        b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2]), name="b")
        layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, w2), b2)
        layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(layer_2)
        # Output layer with linear activation
    with tf.name_scope("output"):
        w3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]), name="w")
        b3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]), name="b")
        out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, w3) + b3
        return out_layer,w1,w2,w3

model_output_OP, w_1,w_2,w_3 = model(input_neurons)

with tf.name_scope("cost"):
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=model_output_OP, labels=known_outputs))

with tf.name_scope("train"):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
    correct_predictions_OP = tf.equal(tf.argmax(model_output_OP, 1), tf.argmax(known_outputs, 1))
    accuracy_OP = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions_OP, "float"), name="Accuracy_op")

with tf.name_scope("summary"):
    model_output_OP_summary = tf.summary.histogram("output", model_output_OP)
    accuracy_OP_summary = tf.summary.scalar("accuracy",accuracy_OP)
    cost_summary = tf.summary.scalar("cost",cost)
    summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("/home/shahzeb/temp/summarylogs/", graph=tf.get_default_graph())

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        _, c, summary,train_accuracy,iw1,iw2,iw3 = sess.run([optimizer, cost,summary_op,accuracy_OP,
                                                 w_1,w_2,w_3
                                                 ],
                                                feed_dict={input_neurons: trainX, known_outputs: trainY})

        print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c), "Accuracy =",train_accuracy)
        #np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
        #print(iw1)
        #print(iw2)
        #print(iw3)
        #rint("--------------")
        writer.add_summary(summary, epoch + 1)

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, "/home/shahzeb/temp/trained_model/hidden_layer_nn.ckpt")
print("Done")
```

and the graphs on tensorboard are as follows.
[image]

Why the cost function value increases after a certain number of epochs. What is wrong and how can i fix.

Answer (score 0):

The key to your problem is the number of epochs. You might be using too many for your given training dataset. So the likely explanation is that you're beginning to overfit at some point around epoch 150.

There is a good [discussion on forums.fast.ai](http://forums.fast.ai/t/number-of-epochs-to-train-on/185/6) on how to deal with such problem. A simple solution is to implement an "early stopping" mechanism, which can be done with Tensorflow's validationmonitor [as described in this tutorial in the Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/monitors/#early-stopping-with-validationmonitor).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Actually, I had a doubt on my model as there was some raw data in the training dataset i.e. some empty rows and with that data, my cost function was not increasing so rapidly but gradually. Once I removed that, the cost function value started to increase rapidly. That's what made me suspicious about my model.